# Javafx style - inheritance not working intuitively, -fx-text-fill not working

Tags: css, javafx, openjfx

I'm new to JavaFX, and am confused by styles. I'm using OpenJFX 13.0.1. I have the following simple scene:

```
val oscs = HBox()
val osc1 = VBox()
val title = Text("Osc 1")
title.styleClass.add("text")
osc1.children.add(title)
oscs.children.add(osc1)

val root = BorderPane()
root.children.add(oscs)
val scene = Scene(root, 500.0,  400.0)
```

I have two issues:

1. `-fx-text-fill` isn't working to color the text, whereas `-fx-fill` is. I.e.

   ```
   .text {
       -fx-fill: #44FFFF;
   }
   ```

   works, whereas:

   ```
   .text {
       -fx-text-fill: #44FFFF;
   }
   ```

   does not. According to the docs, it seems like this is wrong.
2. Inheritance isn't working as I'd expect it to. Shouldn't the child nodes inherit from root?
   The following doesn't work to color the label, regardless of whether it's `-fx-fill` or `-fx-text-fill`.

   ```
   .root {
       -fx-font-size: 24px;
       -fx-font-family: sans-serif;
       -fx-fill: #44FFFF;  
       -fx-background-color: #000000;
       -fx-border-color: #44FF00;
       -fx-border-width: 2px;
   }
   ```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You probably got `Label` and `Text` confused.

`Text` is a subclass of `Shape` and does not provide a `-fx-text-fill` property. Furthermore `Shape`'s `-fx-fill` property is not inherited. See [CSS Reference Guide](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#text).

Other than going with `Label` you could use a descendant selector to assign the fill:

```css
.root .text {
    -fx-fill: #44FFFF;  
}
```

**Edit:**

`Label`'s `-fx-text-fill` is not inherited either. You should be able to fix both cases by specifying `inherit` as value for the `-fx-text-fill` or `-fx-fill` properties. The following should work for `Text`:

```css
.root {
    -fx-fill: #44FFFF;
    -fx-background-color: #000000;
}

.text {
    -fx-fill: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks (I was confusing Label/Text), but this didn't help. The label isn't taking `-fx-text-fill` either. My prior separate rule or your descendant selector exactly as is are required to change the widget color, and it doesn't work to include it in .root.

FWIW I'm familiar with that style page, but it's a total nightmare in terms of layout. Has anybody made a more consumable one? Recursing up the stack 3 or 4 levels and trying to hold what you read 4 levels down in mind is not a pleasant reading experience.

Comment: Sorry, did not look though the reference well enough either... `Labeled` specifies `-fx-text-fill` as `black` by default and not inherited... You'll need to fix this by specifying the property as inherited.As for finding what to look for:You could find out where to search for the property using some code like this: `CssMetaData d = title.getCssMetaData().stream().filter(s -> s.getProperty().equals("-fx-text-fill")).findFirst().orElse(null); System.out.println(d); System.out.println(d.getClass());`. Assuming the class is an anonymus class, you'll find the implementation location via class name.

Comment: But indeed the documentation is not really done well in that regard and often you'll need to look though the skin or `modena.css` to find out the correct ways to style a node via css...